# Wrong ouptut of a c function returning a double called from python

Tags: python, c, output, double

I want to speed up a python code my calling a c function:

I have a the function in vanilla python `sum_and_multiply.py`:

```
def sam_py(lim_sup):
  total = 0
  for i in range(0,lim_sup): # xrange is slower according 
    for j in range(1, lim_sup):            #to my test but more memory-friendly.
      total += (i / j)
  return total
```

then I have the equivalent function in C `sum_and_multiply_c.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>


double sam_c(int lim_sup){
  int i;
  int j;
  double total;
  total = 0;
  double div;
  for (i=0; i<lim_sup; i++){
    for (j=1; j<lim_sup; j++){

      div = (double) i / j;
//      printf("div: %.2f\n", div);
      total += div;
 //     printf("total: %.2f\n", total);
    }
  }
  printf("total: %.2f\n", total);
  return total;
}
```

a file `script.py` which calls the 2 functions

```
from sum_and_multiply import sam_py
import time

lim_sup = 6000

start = time.time()
print(sam_py(lim_sup))
end = time.time()
time_elapsed01 = end - start
print("time elapsed: %.4fs" % time_elapsed01)

from ctypes import *
my_c_fun = CDLL("sum_and_multiply_c.so")
start = time.time()
print(my_c_fun.sam_c(lim_sup))
end = time.time()
time_elapsed02 = end - start
print("time elapsed: %.4fs" % time_elapsed02)
print("Speedup coefficient: %.2fx" % (time_elapsed01/time_elapsed02))
```

and finally a shell script `bashscript.zsh` which compile the C code and then call `script.py`

```
cc -fPIC -shared -o sum_and_multiply_c.so sum_and_multiply_c.c
python script.py
```

Here is the output:

```
166951817.45311993
time elapsed: 2.3095s
total: 166951817.45
20
time elapsed: 0.3016s
Speedup coefficient: 7.66x
```

Here is my question although the c function calculate correctly the result (as output 166951817.45 via printf) its output when passed to python is 20 which wrong. How could I have 166951817.45 instead?

**Edit** the problem persists after changing the last part of the `script.py` as follows:

```
from ctypes import *
my_c_fun = CDLL("sum_and_multiply_c.so")
my_c_fun.restype = c_double
my_c_fun.argtypes = [ c_int ]
start = time.time()
print(my_c_fun.sam_c(lim_sup))
end = time.time()
time_elapsed02 = end - start
print("time elapsed: %.4fs" % time_elapsed02)
print("Speedup coefficient: %.2fx" % (time_elapsed01/time_elapsed02))
```

Comment: you could simply not do either and use numpy

Comment: and if `xrange` is more memory-friendly, you're using the long-obsolete Python2 series. That's been end-of-lifed. you should really be using Python3.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MarcusMüller. But this is also for the sake of exercice... ;)

Comment: yeah, don't exercise on Python2. There's no excuse. It's dead.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, according to this : https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-use-pythons-xrange-and-range/ `xrange` (which I am not using) is deprecated. I don't see what you mean

Comment: yes, `xrange` is deprecated **in Python2**, which is dead. It's deprecated because Python3's `range` is equivalent to Python2's `xrange`, and that lead to confusion. (note that the article you linked to is 9 years old, and even then the Python folks were already telling everyone to stop using Python2. The article still teaching Python2 is not great, but it was 2013, and thus much more acceptable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assuming Python can "see" your function returns a `double`. But it can't. C doesn't "encode" the return type in anything, so whoever calls a function from a library needs to know its return type, or risk misinterpreting it.

You should have read the documentation of `CDLL` before using it! If you say this is for the sake of exercise, then that exercise needs to include reading the documentation (that's what good programmers do, no excuses).

> ```
> class ctypes.CDLL(name, mode=DEFAULT_MODE, handle=None, use_errno=False, use_last_error=False)
> ```

> Instances of this class represent loaded shared libraries. Functions in these libraries use the standard C calling convention, and are **assumed to return `int`.**

(emphasis mine.)

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html#return-types is your friend (and the top of the page will tell you that Python2 is dead and you shouldn't use it, even if you insist on it. I'm sure you have a better reason than the Python developers themselves!).

```py
my_c_fun = CDLL("sum_and_multiply_c.so")
sam_c = my_c_fun.sam_c
sam_c.restype = c_double
sam_c.argtypes = [ c_int ]
value = sam_c(6000)
print(value)
```

is the way to go.